# How to properly destructure variable if it can be absent inside property?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable inside React component based on server response, the variable can be located either inside prop.prop or prop. How can I properly destructure this case?

```
 const { myVar } = prop.prop || prop
```

Comment: is `prop` an object? do you have an example with data?

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: @NickParsons With current approach `myVar` will always be destructured from `prop.prop` even if its not present inside that.

Comment: @MaheerAli oh, I see now. I didn't understand the question at first but makes sense now

Comment: `const { p, q } = {...prop.prop, ...prop};` ?

Comment: @Yoshi, in other order, because the last overwrites the first one.

Comment: @NinaScholz You're right, wasn't too sure which one's the default (if any) ;)

Comment: @MaheerAli *With current approach myVar will always be destructured from prop.prop even if its not present inside that.* - that is not true...

Comment: @tevemadar Can you please explain how.

Comment: @MaheerAli https://stackoverflow.com/a/59425326/7916438 - the code in the question works fine here as a JS snippet, and also works in react. Yes, OP might mean that `prop.prop` is present all the time, but he refused to provide examples, everything is just guesswork.

Comment: @tevemadar  I am sure you misunderstood the question. and also your answer is wrong if `test({ myVar: 10, prop:{} });` is called it will return `undefined`.

Comment: @tevemadar I am supposed to answer what OP have asked. There are too many possibilities. If OP didn't mentioned `prop.prop` could be absent sometimes then it means it can't. According to your point of view. Your code won't work if the `prop` itself is `undefined`.

Comment: @MaheerAli well, what appeared in my imagination was that OP either gets an object containing `myVar` directly, or he gets the same kind of object wrapped (as `prop`) into an outer object, like one describing an error - or even success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use it as

```
const { prop: { myVar } = prop } = prop;
```

---

Use the combination of nested destructure and default values. This is sample code to show different type of props input. In Real code you can just use one const statement.

```js
var propFlat = { myVar1: "flat-1", myVar2: "flat-2" };

var propNested = { prop: { myVar1: "nested-1", myVar2: "nested-2" } };

const { prop: { myVar1 } = propFlat } = propFlat;
const { prop: { myVar2 } = propNested } = propNested;

console.log(myVar1); // output "flat-1"
console.log(myVar2); // output "nested-2"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ternary operator.

```
 const { myVar } = prop.prop.myVar ? prop.prop : prop
```

If your `myVar` could contain any falsy value then you can use `hasOwnProperty`

```
 const { myVar } = prop.prop.hasOwnProperty('myVar') ? prop.prop : prop
```

You avoid destructuring syntax completely.

```
 const myVar = prop.prop.myVar || prop.myVar
```

I would use the last way if its sure that `myVar` will never be falsy value.

Comment: `const { myVar } = prop.prop.myVar ? //...` will throw error right there, if `prop.prop` is not set.

Comment: @mbojko But OP didn't mentioned that `prop.prop` could be `undefined`. He just said `myVar` will be inside `prop.prop` or `prop`. If `myVar` isn't inside `prop.prop` it doesn't mean its `undefined`

Comment: ... which makes all of these unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

Ehm, I know it is a browser and not react, but this snippet works for me in Chrome:

```js
function test(prop){
  const { myVar } = prop.prop || prop;
  console.log(myVar);
}

test({myVar:10});
test({prop:{myVar:20}});
```

---

The approach works with React too. I went to [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/reactjs), and modified the default component as

```
[...]
  render() {
    function test(prop){
      const { myVar } = prop.prop || prop;
      return myVar;                          
    }
    let asd=test({myVar:10});
    let qwe=test({prop:{myVar:20}});
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit {asd}<code>src/App.js</code>{qwe} and save to reload.
[...]
```

The result is rendered as expected:

> ```
> Edit 10src/App.js20 and save to reload.
> ```

Both 10 and 20 are there.

Comment: Does this answer the question? No, not really.

Comment: @JonasWilms: Well, the tag says "JavaScript", and it is JavaScript. It even works on a 3-year old iOS Safari, so I really-really doubt that it would not work on React, despite of its different JS engine.

Comment: @JonasWilms it works in react too. Forwarded your downvote to the question along with a close.