# How to destructurate an object property that sometimes is received as null

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, destructuring

I have this object below that I receive via API, but sometimes the *SimplesNacional* property comes as null.
How do I destructure(??) it only when it's not `null`, since it has some nested properties that break my program in the destructuration?

This is the object:

```js
const {
    Retorno: {
        ReceitaPJ: {
            NumeroInscricao: numeroInscricao,
            Matriz: matriz,
            DataAbertura: dataAbertura,
            NomeEmpresarial: nomeEmpresarial,
            NomeFantasia: nomeFantasia,
            NaturezaJuridica: naturezaJuridica,
            SituacaoCadastral: situacaoCadastral,
        },
        SimplesNacional: {
            SituacaoSimplesNacional: situacaoSimplesNacional,
            SituacaoSIMEI: situacaoSIMEI,
            SimplesNacionalPeriodosAnteriores: simplesNacionalPeriodosAnteriores,
            SIMEIPeriodosAnteriores,
            DataConsulta: dataConsulta,
        },
        CadastroPJ: {
            Telefones: telefones,
            Enderecos: enderecos,
            Emails: emails,
            Socios: socios,
        },
    },
} = response;
```

This is the usage:

```js
result.data = {
    cadastroPJ: {
        numeroInscricao,
        matriz,
        dataAbertura,
        nomeEmpresarial,
        nomeFantasia,
        naturezaJuridica,
        situacaoCadastral,
    },
    simplesNacional: {
        nomeEmpresarial,
        situacaoSimplesNacional,
        situacaoSIMEI,
        simplesNacionalPeriodosAnteriores,
        SIMEIPeriodosAnteriores,
        dataConsulta,
    },
    telefones: telefones.map((x) => ({
        numero: x.TelefoneComDDD,
    })),
    enderecos: enderecos.map((x) => ({
        logradouro: x.Logradouro,
        numero: x.Numero,
        bairro: x.Bairro,
        cidade: x.Cidade,
        uf: x.UF,
        cep: x.CEP,
    })),
    emails: emails.map((x) => ({
        endereco: x.EnderecoEmail,
    })),
    socios: socios.map((x) => ({
        documento: x.Documento,
        nome: x.Nome,
        percentualParticipacao: x.PercentualParticipacao,
        dataEntrada: x.DataEntrada,
    })),
};
```

Visual Studio Code terminal says:

> Cannot destructure property `SituacaoSimplesNacional` of `undefined` or `null`.

because the property `SimplesNacional` is `null`.

Comment: Did you mean "response" is the "result" in second snippet? also can you check if this answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59425002/how-to-properly-destructure-variable-if-it-can-be-absent-inside-property/59425726#59425726

Comment: Yep, result is the response properties treated to a new object.

Comment: Is the property there with a null value, or omitted completely? The solution is different for the two cases.

Comment: @Barmar the property is there with a null value.

Comment: Your destructuring pattern is very different from the object. There's no `CadastroPJ` property in the `result.data` object. There's no `Retorno` property, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const {
  Retorno: {
    ReceitaPJ: {
      NumeroInscricao: numeroInscricao,
      Matriz: matriz,
      DataAbertura: dataAbertura,
      NomeEmpresarial: nomeEmpresarial,
      NomeFantasia: nomeFantasia,
      NaturezaJuridica: naturezaJuridica,
      SituacaoCadastral: situacaoCadastral,
    },
    SimplesNacional,
    CadastroPJ: {
      Telefones: telefones,
      Enderecos: enderecos,
      Emails: emails,
      Socios: socios,
    },
  },
} = response

if (SimplesNacional) {
  var {
    SituacaoSimplesNacional: situacaoSimplesNacional,
    SituacaoSIMEI: situacaoSIMEI,
    SimplesNacionalPeriodosAnteriores: simplesNacionalPeriodosAnteriores,
    SIMEIPeriodosAnteriores,
    DataConsulta: dataConsulta,
  } = SimplesNacional
}
```

Just make it in two steps

**EDIT:** if you want use const...

```js
const {
   SituacaoSimplesNacional: situacaoSimplesNacional,
   SituacaoSIMEI: situacaoSIMEI,
   SimplesNacionalPeriodosAnteriores: simplesNacionalPeriodosAnteriores,
   SIMEIPeriodosAnteriores,
   DataConsulta: dataConsulta,
 } = (SimplesNacional || {})
```

but anyway, deep in object will throw an error later...

Comment: This doesn't work with `const` though

Comment: This works, but it doesn't look right. I'm gonna use it like this because I'm short in time, but eventually I'm gonna sit down and make more research on this. Thanks

Comment: Keep it simple, prioritize maintainability, forget about tricks and quick solves, the next dev will be grateful <3